# How to import a large number of RData files at the same time

Tags: r, import

```
fs::dir_ls(
  
  path = paste("C:/Users/",Sys.info()["user"],
               "/Dropbox/66_COHORTE_obe/00_RAW_DATA - copie/1_GROUPE BARIA/DIAG/CLEAN DATASET",
               sep = ""),
  glob="*DIAG*.RDS",
  type="file"
)%>%{
  tibble(path=.,
         data=map(., .%>%
                    readRDS()))
}->all_files_DIAG_CLEAN
```

I used the above code to import a large number of RDS files from my folder following the file name pattern.

I would like to try the same thing to import RData files

```
fs::dir_ls(
  
  path = paste("C:/Users/",Sys.info()["user"],
               "/Dropbox/66_COHORTE_obe/00_RAW_DATA - copie/1_GROUPE BARIA/DIAG/CLEAN DATASET",
               sep = ""),
  glob="*DIAG*.RData",
  type="file"
)%>%{
  tibble(path=.,
         data=map(., .%>%
                    load()))
}->all_files_DIAG_CLEAN
```

I replaced readRDS() by load(). I understand why this one didn't work because you can't assign load() to an object.

I tried also this

```
fs::dir_ls(
  
  path = paste("C:/Users/",Sys.info()["user"],
               "/Dropbox/66_COHORTE_obe/00_RAW_DATA - copie/1_GROUPE BARIA/DIAG/CLEAN DATASET",
               sep = ""),
  glob="*DIAG*.RDS",
  type="file"
)%>%{
  tibble(path=.,
         map(., .%>%
                    load()))
}->all_files_DIAG_CLEAN
```

that is without assigning load () to an object but I still can not import myfiles.

Can anyone suggest something, please?

Answer (score 0):

This should work... with some caveats. You may need to perform additional processing to ensure that the tibble in `all_files_DIAG_CLEAN` is well formed.

```r
fs::dir_ls(
  path = paste('C:/Users/', 
               Sys.info()[ 'user' ],
               '/Dropbox/66_COHORTE_obe/00_RAW_DATA - copie/1_GROUPE BARIA/DIAG/CLEAN DATASET',
               sep = ''),
  glob='*DIAG*.RData',
  type='file'
) %>%
  {
    var_names <- lapply(., load) %>% unlist # I assume that there is only 1 variable stored in each .rdata file, this might not be a valid assumption   
    vals <- lapply(var_names, get) %>% unlist # I assume that each value stored is a vector of length 1, this might not be a valid assumption
    tibble(path = ., value = vals)
  } -> all_files_DIAG_CLEAN
```